# Error upgrading pip in virtualenv in Windows

Tags: python, powershell, pip

I'm creating a virtual environment as such:

```
$ py -m venv venv
```

Then activate it (I use Powershell):

```
> venv/Scripts/activate
```

Now I run:

```
(venv) PS D:/...> pip install -U pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\azure\app-registration\ms-identity-python-webapp\venv\lib\site-packages (21.1.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 1.3 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\..\\venv\\scripts\\pip.exe'
Check the permissions.
```

Why is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+OSError+WinError+5+Access+is+denied+pip.exe

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

It happening because your os didn't give the permission to create virtualenvironment.

You can solve it by opening powershell administrative then paste this

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

then click enter

after that select Yes To All

then restart your ide

it must be solve